# Write an if statement for a list element in Pandas dataframe cell

Tags: pandas, string, list, dataframe, if-statement

I have a Pandas dataframe with a column "genres" which contains a list as cell value:

```
import pandas
df = pd.DataFrame([
{
    "title": "The Godfather: Part II",
    "genres": ["crime", "drama"],
    "director": "Fracis Ford Coppola"
},
{
    "title": "The Dark Knight",
    "genres": ["actionmovie", "crime", "drama"],
    "director": "Christopher Nolan"
}
])
```

I'm trying to write an if statement to add a column "action_crime_movie" with values True or False based on matching parts of the string elements in the genres list.
In other words: the 2nd line contains the word "action" (in "actionmovie") and "crime" (in "crime") so it should have the value True for "action_crime_movie".

```
if ("action", "crime") in df["genres"]: df["action_crime_movie"] = True
else df["action_crime_movie"] = False
```

However, with the above query the value was set to False...

Could anyone help me solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily by using `apply lambda`

```
df["action_crime_movie"] = df["genres"].apply(lambda x: True if ("action" in str(x)) and ("crime" in str(x)) else False)

print(df["action_crime_movie"])
0    False
1     True
Name: action_crime_movie, dtype: bool
```

Comment: Thank you for this nice solution! What if I want to combine this with an "or"/"and" statement on another column? For example: "action_crime_movie_Nolan" can only be True if the above statement is True AND "director" = "Christopher Nolan"

Comment: @olive Then you will have to apply a lambda function on complete dataframe with axis = 1 and inside the function you can access the column by simple indexing. It will be something like this.
df.apply(lambda x: True if ("action" in str(x["genres"])) and ("crime" in str(x["genres"])) and (x["director"] == "Christopher Nolan") else False, axis = 1)

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much! All my issues are solved

Comment: @olive My pleasure!